# While writing DocumentTermMatrix in excel file facing error : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: r

**i have a generated matrix from my DTM  and that is big matrix (7137144 elements, 54.9 MB)**

```
tdmMatrix2 <- as.matrix(removeSparseTerms(dtmr, 0.999))
```

**after that i want to write my tdmMatrix2 to the xls file and facing this error:
Error in .jcall(cell, "V", "setCellValue", value) : 
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded**

**I used below function for the same**

```
for(i in seq_along(tdmMatrix2))
{
  gc()
  jgc()
write.xlsx(tdmMatrix2[i], "DTM2.xlsx")
}
```

**but it is not giving me the right solution as the file has wrong values..
Please suggest some way for this.
this is my dtm:

> c
>   <>
>   Non-/sparse entries: 41008/7096136
>   Sparsity           : 99%
>   Maximal term length: 19
>   Weighting          : term frequency (tf)**

Comment: Excel is always a tough job since it's dependent on Java. ```write.csv``` should help you!

Comment: you probably use `xlsx` package which depends on Java. For writing to Excel, you should give a go to `openxlsx` package or in developpement `writexl` package from rOpensci. Both have no dependencies to Java